# Email status is not tracking

Tags: email

I send a mail to my contacts but emailstatus object not showing the status may i know what i have to do for this.

my contact images are[image]

Email status is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Enable Email Tracking* (Setup > Customize > Activities > Activity Settings) must be enabled, and the template or email must be sent in HTML mode. Tracking status is not available in text-only templates, text-only email mode, or Visualforce template that uses only plain text.